# Why my code, which is sorting and searching from the csv file, not showing all of the result from the data?

Tags: c, csv, search, quicksort, binary-search

I Create a program that contain something like this

```
What Do you want to do? 
1. Display data
2. search data
3. sort data
4. export data
5. exit
```

I already created the code from option `1` until option `2`, the rest of the code still not built, so ignore the rest of `switch` case code

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char location[100];
    char city[100];
    int price;
    int room;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[100];
    char furnish[100];
} data;

//Quick Sort by location//
void swap(data *a, data *b)
{
    data temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partitionL(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    char pivot[1000];
    strcpy(pivot, arr[high].location);
    int i = low - 1;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[j].location, pivot) < 0)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortL(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionL(arr, low, high);
        sortL(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortL(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort by location

//Quick Sort by city//

int partitionC(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    char pivot[1000];
    strcpy(pivot, arr[high].city);
    int i = low - 1;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[j].city, pivot) < 0)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortC(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionC(arr, low, high);
        sortC(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortC(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort by city

//Quick Sort by type//

int partitionT(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    char pivot[1000];
    strcpy(pivot, arr[high].type);
    int i = low - 1;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[j].type, pivot) < 0)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortT(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionT(arr, low, high);
        sortT(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortT(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort by type

//Quick Sort by furnish//

int partitionF(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    char pivot[1000];
    strcpy(pivot, arr[high].furnish);
    int i = low - 1;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[j].furnish, pivot) < 0)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortF(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionF(arr, low, high);
        sortF(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortF(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort by furnish

//Quick Sort by price//

int partitionP(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot= arr[high].price;
    int i = low - 1;
  
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j].price < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortP(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionP(arr, low, high);
        sortP(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortP(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort price

//Quick Sort by room//

int partitionR(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot= arr[high].room;
    int i = low - 1;
  
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j].room < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortR(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionR(arr, low, high);
        sortR(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortR(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort room

//Quick Sort by bathroom//

int partitionB(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high].bathroom;
    int i = low - 1;
   
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j].bathroom < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortB(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionB(arr, low, high);
        sortB(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortB(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort bathroom

//Quick Sort by carpark//

int partitionK(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    int pivot = arr[high].carpark;
    int i = low - 1;
   
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j].carpark < pivot)
        {
            i++;
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
    return i + 1;
}

void sortK(data arr[], int low, int high)
{
    if (low < high)
    {
        int pi = partitionK(arr, low, high);
        sortK(arr, low, pi - 1);
        sortK(arr, pi + 1, high);
    }
}

/// end of quick sort carpark

// Search location
int searchL(data array[], char target[], int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while(low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        char value[100];
        strcpy(value, array[middle].location);
        
        if (strcmp(value, target) < 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else if (strcmp(value, target) > 0)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; //target found
    }
    
    return -1;
}
//end of search location

//Search city
int searchC(data array[], char target[], int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        char value[100];
        strcpy(value, array[middle].city);
        
        if (strcmp(value, target) < 0)
           low = middle + 1;
        else if (strcmp(value, target) > 0)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
           return middle; //target found
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search city

//Search type
int searchT(data array[], char target[], int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        char value[100];
        strcpy(value, array[middle].type);
        
        if (strcmp(value, target) < 0)
           low = middle + 1;
        else if (strcmp(value, target) > 0)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; //target found
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search type

//Search furnish
int searchF(data array[], char target[], int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        char value[100];
        strcpy(value, array[middle].furnish);
        
        if (strcmp(value, target) < 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else if (strcmp(value, target) > 0)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; //target found
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search furnish

//search price
int searchP(data array[], int target, int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int value = array[middle].price;
        
        if (value < target)
            low = middle + 1;
        else if (value > target)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; 
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search price

//search room
int searchR(data array[], int target, int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int value = array[middle].room;
        
        if (value < target)
            low = middle + 1;
        else if (value > target)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; 
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search room

//search Bathroom
int searchB(data array[], int target, int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int value = array[middle].bathroom;
        
        if (value < target)
            low = middle + 1;
        else if (value > target)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; 
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search Bathroom

//search carpark
int searchK(data array[], int target, int start, int array_length) {
    
    int low = start;
    int high = array_length - 1;
    
    while (low <= high) {
        
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        int value = array[middle].carpark;
        
        if (value < target)
            low = middle + 1;
        else if (value > target)
            high = middle - 1;
        else
            return middle; 
    }
    
    return -1;
}
// end of search carpark


int main()
{
    data house[4000];

    FILE *file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    if(file == NULL){
        printf("File is missing!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buffer[1000];
    fgets(buffer, 1000, file);
    char header[1000]; strcpy(header, buffer);

    int n = 0;
    while (fgets(buffer, 1000, file))
    {
        char *token = strtok(buffer, ",");
        strcpy(house[n].location, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(house[n].city, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].price = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].room = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].bathroom = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        house[n].carpark = atoi(token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        strcpy(house[n].type, token);

        token = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
        strcpy(house[n].furnish, token);

        n++;
    }

    fclose(file);

//  //for checking the output and file processed
//      printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
//      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
//      {
//             printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[i].location, house[i].city, house[i].price, house[i].room, house[i].bathroom, house[i].carpark, house[i].type, house[i].furnish);
//      }

    int input = 0;

    do {
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("1.  Display data\n");
        printf("2.  Search Data\n");
        printf("3.  Sort Data\n");
        printf("4.  Export Data\n");
        printf("5.  Exit\n");
        printf("Your choice: "); 
        scanf("%d", &input);
    
        switch (input)
        {
          case 1:
            printf("Number of rows: "); 
            int rows;
            scanf("%d", &rows);
            printf("\n");
            printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[i].location, house[i].city, house[i].price, house[i].room, house[i].bathroom, house[i].carpark, house[i].type, house[i].furnish);
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        
          case 2:
            printf("Choose column: ");
            char column[100];
            scanf("%s", column); 
            printf("What data do you want to find? ");
            char search[100];
            scanf("%s", search);
            
            if (strcmp(column, "Location") == 0) {
                sortL(house, 0, n-1);
                int idx = -1;
                if (searchL(house, search, idx, n ) != -1)
                {   
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while((idx = searchL(house, search, idx, n)) != -1){
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            } 
            else if (strcmp(column, "City") == 0) {
                sortC(house, 0, n-1);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchC(house, search, idx, n ) != -1)
                {
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchC(house, search, idx, n)) != -1){
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(column, "Price") == 0) {
                sortP(house, 0, n-1);
                int target = atoi(search);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchP(house, target, idx, n) != -1) {
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchP(house, target, idx, n)) != -1){
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(column, "Rooms") == 0) {
                sortR(house, 0, n-1);
                int target = atoi(search);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchR(house, target, idx, n) != -1) {
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchR(house, target, idx, n)) != -1){
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(column, "Bathroom") == 0) {
                sortB(house, 0, n-1);
                int target = atoi(search);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchB(house, target, idx, n) != -1) {
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchB(house, target, idx, n)) != -1){
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(column, "Carpark") == 0) {
                sortK(house, 0, n-1);
                int target = atoi(search);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchK(house, target, idx, n) != -1) {
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchK(house, target, idx, n)) != -1) {
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(column, "Type") == 0) {
                sortT(house, 0, n-1);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchT(house, search, idx, n ) != -1)
                {   
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchT(house, search, idx, n)) != -1) {
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            }
            else if (strcmp(column, "Furnish") == 0) {
                sortF(house, 0, n-1);
                int idx = 0;
                if (searchF(house, search, idx, n ) != -1)
                {   
                    printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n", "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom", "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                    while ((idx = searchF(house, search, idx, n)) != -1) {
                        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n", house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price, house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark, house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                        idx++; 
                    }
                    printf("\n");
                } else {
                    printf("Data Not Found!\n");
                }
            }
            break;
    
          case 3: 
    
          default:
            break;
        }
    } while (input == 1 || input == 2 || input == 3 || input == 4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the [data.csv](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aku57Ir1WmIgc8i1qVN8DK2yras?e=VbbuDu)

the display data option works perfectly, so just ignore it.
The search data option not working perfectly. Ok for example, I try to search city : `Kuala-Lumpur`
my program just showing 12 data, from thousand of actual data. It's also the same for other column like location, price, bathroom etc. It's just showing maximal 12 data. I confuse. Please help me figure out what wrong with my code.
this is [the image for more detailed explanation](https://imgur.com/a/vC82B1r), what i want to say.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search functions do not return the **first** matching entry, they return the first one they find, which might be in the middle of the series of matching entries.  You should modify the program 2 ways:

- make the search functions return the first entry
- change the `while` loop to iterate on the entries as long as `idx < n` and the condition is met. No need to call `search again with a restricted range.

Here is a modified `searchL` function:

```
// Search location
int searchL(data array[], char target[], int array_length) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = array_length;

    while (low < high) {
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (strcmp(array[middle].location, target) < 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            high = middle;
    }
    if (low < array_length && !strcmp(array[low].location, target))
        return low;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Here is the modified part of the `main()` function:

```
        if (strcmp(column, "Location") == 0) {
            sortL(house, 0, n-1);
            int idx = searchL(house, search, n);
            if (idx != -1) {
                printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n",
                       "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom",
                       "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
                while (idx < n && !strcmp(search, house[idx].location)) {
                    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n",
                           house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price,
                           house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark,
                           house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
                    idx++;
                }
                printf("\n");
            } else {
                printf("Data Not Found!\n");
            }
        }
```

You would greatly simplify and shorten the code by

- using `qsort` to sort the array, only writing a comparison function
- using the comparison function to locate the first matching entry for a given test.
- writing a utility function to dump the database and calling it in appropriate places.

Here is a simplified version for you to study:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char location[100];
    char city[100];
    int price;
    int room;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[100];
    char furnish[100];
} data;

//Comparison functions//
int compare_location(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return strcmp(a->location, b->location);
}

int compare_city(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return strcmp(a->city, b->city);
}

int compare_price(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return (a->price > b->price) - (a->price < b->price);
}

int compare_room(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return (a->room > b->room) - (a->room < b->room);
}

int compare_bathroom(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return (a->bathroom > b->bathroom) - (a->bathroom < b->bathroom);
}

int compare_carpark(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return (a->carpark > b->carpark) - (a->carpark < b->carpark);
}

int compare_type(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return strcmp(a->type, b->type);
}

int compare_furnish(const data *a, const data *b) {
    return strcmp(a->furnish, b->furnish);
}

//Generic Quick Sort for data type//
void data_swap(data *a, data *b)
{
    if (a != b) {
        data temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
    }
}

int data_partition(data arr[], int low, int high, int cmp(const data *a, const data *b))
{
    data pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low;

    for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
        if (cmp(&arr[j], &pivot) < 0) {
            data_swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    data_swap(&arr[i], &arr[high]);
    return i;
}

void data_sort(data arr[], int low, int high, int cmp(const data *a, const data *b))
{
    if (low < high) {
        int pi = data_partition(arr, low, high, cmp);
        data_sort(arr, low, pi - 1, cmp);
        data_sort(arr, pi + 1, high, cmp);
    }
}

//Generic Search data
// return -1 if not found
// return index of first match and store index past the last match in *end
int data_search(data array[], int array_length,
                int cmp(const data *a, const data *b),
                const data *target, int *end)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = array_length;

    while (low < high) {
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (cmp(&array[middle], target) < 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            high = middle;
    }
    for (high = low; high < array_length && !cmp(&array[high], target); high++)
        continue;
    if (low < high) {
        *end = high;
        return low;
    } else {
        *end = -1;
        return -1;
    }
}

// end of search carpark
void dump_rows(data *house, int idx, int end) {
    printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n",
           "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom",
           "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
    while (idx < end) {
        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n",
               house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price,
               house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark,
               house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
        idx++;
    }
}

//discard rest of input line
int input_flush(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    data house[4000];

    FILE *file = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("File is missing!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char header[1000];
    fgets(header, sizeof header, file);

    char buffer[1000];
    int n = 0;
    while (n < 4000 && fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, file))
    {
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%99[^,],%99[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%99[^,],%99[^,\n]",
                   house[n].location, house[n].city, &house[n].price,
                   &house[n].room, &house[n].bathroom, &house[n].carpark,
                   house[n].type, house[n].furnish) == 8)
        {
            n++;
        }  else {
            printf("invalid record: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    //  //for checking the output and file processed
    //  dump_rows(house, 0, n);
    int done = 0;
    while (!done) {
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("1.  Display data\n");
        printf("2.  Search Data\n");
        printf("3.  Sort Data\n");
        printf("4.  Export Data\n");
        printf("5.  Exit\n");
        printf("Your choice: ");

        int input;
        int res = scanf("%d", &input);
        input_flush();
        if (res != 1)
            break;

        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("Number of rows: ");
            int rows;
            res = scanf("%d", &rows);
            input_flush();
            if (res != 1)
                break;
            printf("\n");
            if (rows > n)
                rows = n;
            dump_rows(house, 0, rows);
            printf("\n");
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Choose column: ");
            char column[100];
            res = scanf("%99s", column);
            input_flush();
            if (res != 1)
                break;
            data target = { 0 };
            int (*cmp)(const data *a, const data *b) = NULL;

            if (strcmp(column, "Location") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_location;
                printf("What location do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.location);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "City") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_city;
                printf("What city do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.city);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "Price") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_price;
                printf("What price do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.price);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "Room") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_room;
                printf("How many rooms do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.room);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "Bathroom") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_bathroom;
                printf("How many bathrooms price do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.bathroom);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "Carpark") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_carpark;
                printf("How many carparks do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.carpark);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "Type") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_type;
                printf("What location do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.type);
            } else
            if (strcmp(column, "Furnish") == 0) {
                cmp = compare_furnish;
                printf("What value of furnish do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.furnish);
            } else {
                printf("unknown column: %s\n", column);
                break;
            }
            input_flush();
            if (res != 1) {
                printf("input error\n");
                break;
            }
            data_sort(house, 0, n-1, cmp);
            int end;
            int idx = data_search(house, n, cmp, &target, &end);
            if (idx != -1) {
                printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                dump_rows(house, idx, end);
                printf("\n");
            } else {
                printf("Data Not Found!\n");
            }
            break;

        case 3:
        case 4:
            break;
        case 5:
        default:
            done = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a more advanced version using `qsort`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char location[100];
    char city[100];
    int price;
    int room;
    int bathroom;
    int carpark;
    char type[100];
    char furnish[100];
} data;

enum field {
    LOCATION, CITY, PRICE, ROOM, BATHROOM, CARPARK, TYPE, FURNISH, FIELD_NUM, NONE = -1
};

//discard rest of input line
int input_flush(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        continue;
    return c;
}

enum field get_data_field(void) {
    printf("Choose column: ");
    char column[100];
    int res = scanf("%99s", column);
    input_flush();
    if (res != 1) {
        printf("invalid input\n");
        return NONE;
    }
    if (!strcmp(column, "Location"))
        return LOCATION;
    if (!strcmp(column, "City"))
        return CITY;
    if (!strcmp(column, "Price"))
        return PRICE;
    if (!strcmp(column, "Room"))
        return ROOM;
    if (!strcmp(column, "Bathroom"))
        return BATHROOM;
    if (!strcmp(column, "Carpark"))
        return CARPARK;
    if (!strcmp(column, "Type"))
        return TYPE;
    if (!strcmp(column, "Furnish"))
        return FURNISH;

    int colnum = atoi(column);
    if (colnum > 0 && colnum <= FIELD_NUM)
        return colnum - 1;

    printf("unknown column: %s\n", column);
    return NONE;
}

//Comparison functions//
int compare_location(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return strcmp(a->location, b->location);
}

int compare_city(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return strcmp(a->city, b->city);
}

int compare_price(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return (a->price > b->price) - (a->price < b->price);
}

int compare_room(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return (a->room > b->room) - (a->room < b->room);
}

int compare_bathroom(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return (a->bathroom > b->bathroom) - (a->bathroom < b->bathroom);
}

int compare_carpark(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return (a->carpark > b->carpark) - (a->carpark < b->carpark);
}

int compare_type(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return strcmp(a->type, b->type);
}

int compare_furnish(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const data *a = aa;
    const data *b = bb;
    return strcmp(a->furnish, b->furnish);
}

#ifdef USE_QSORT

void data_sort(data arr[], int count, int cmp(const void *aa, const void *bb)) {
    // using qsort:
    qsort(arr, count, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
}

#else

//Generic Quick Sort for data type//
void data_swap(data *a, data *b) {
    if (a != b) {
        data temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;
    }
}

int data_partition(data arr[], int low, int high, int cmp(const void *aa, const void *bb))
{
    data pivot = arr[high];
    int i = low;

    for (int j = low + 1; j < high; j++) {
        if (cmp(&arr[j], &pivot) < 0) {
            data_swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    data_swap(&arr[i], &arr[high]);
    return i;
}

void data_quick_sort(data arr[], int low, int high, int cmp(const void *aa, const void *bb))
{
    if (low < high) {
        int pi = data_partition(arr, low, high, cmp);
        data_quick_sort(arr, low, pi - 1, cmp);
        data_quick_sort(arr, pi + 1, high, cmp);
    }
}

void data_sort(data arr[], int count, int cmp(const void *aa, const void *bb))
{
    // using our quick sort implementation
    data_quick_sort(arr, 0, count - 1, cmp);
}

#endif

//Generic Search data
int data_search(data array[], int array_length,
                int cmp(const void *aa, const void *bb),
                const data *target, int *end)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = array_length;

    while (low < high) {
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        if (cmp(&array[middle], target) < 0)
            low = middle + 1;
        else
            high = middle;
    }
    for (high = low; high < array_length && !cmp(&array[high], target); high++)
        continue;
    if (low < high) {
        *end = high;
        return low;
    } else {
        *end = -1;
        return -1;
    }
}

// end of search carpark
void data_print(const data *house, int idx, int end, int header) {
    if (header) {
        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10s %-5s %-10s %-8s %-10s %-10s\n",
               "Location", "City", "Price", "Rooms", "Bathroom",
               "Carpark", "Type", "Furnish");
    }
    while (idx < end) {
        printf("%-25s %-15s %-10d %-5d %-10d %-8d %-10s %-10s\n",
               house[idx].location, house[idx].city, house[idx].price,
               house[idx].room, house[idx].bathroom, house[idx].carpark,
               house[idx].type, house[idx].furnish);
        idx++;
    }
}

int data_read(data *house, int count, const char *fname, char *header, size_t header_len) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s\n", fname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    if (!fgets(header, header_len, file))
        *header = '\0';

    char buffer[1000];
    int buffer_len = sizeof(buffer);
    int n = 0;
    while (n < count && fgets(buffer, buffer_len, file))
    {
        if (sscanf(buffer, "%99[^,],%99[^,],%d,%d,%d,%d,%99[^,],%99[^,\n]",
                   house[n].location, house[n].city, &house[n].price,
                   &house[n].room, &house[n].bathroom, &house[n].carpark,
                   house[n].type, house[n].furnish) == 8)
        {
            n++;
        }  else {
            printf("invalid record: %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return n;
}

int data_write(const data *house, const char *fname, int start, int end) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fname, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", fname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    fputs("Location 1,Location 2,Price,Rooms,Bathrooms,CarParks,Type,Furnish\n", file);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        fprintf(file, "%s,%s,%d,%d,%d,%d,%s,%s\n",
                house[i].location, house[i].city, house[i].price,
                house[i].room, house[i].bathroom, house[i].carpark,
                house[i].type, house[i].furnish);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return end - start;
}

int main(void)
{
    data house[4000];
    char header[1000];
    int n = data_read(house, 4000, "data.csv", header, sizeof header);
    if (n < 0)
        return 1;

    //  for checking the output and file processed
    //  data_print(house, 0, n, 1);
    int done = 0;
    while (!done) {
        printf("\nWhat do you want to do?\n");
        printf("1.  Display data\n");
        printf("2.  Search data\n");
        printf("3.  Sort data\n");
        printf("4.  Export data\n");
        printf("5.  Exit\n");
        printf("Your choice: ");

        int input;
        int res = scanf("%d", &input);
        input_flush();
        if (res != 1)
            break;

        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            printf("Number of rows: ");
            int rows;
            res = scanf("%d", &rows);
            input_flush();
            if (res != 1)
                break;
            printf("\n");
            if (rows > n)
                rows = n;
            data_print(house, 0, rows, 1);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            data target = { 0 };
            int (*cmp)(const void *aa, const void *bb) = NULL;

            switch (+get_data_field()) {
            case LOCATION:
                cmp = compare_location;
                printf("What location do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.location);
                break;
            case CITY:
                cmp = compare_city;
                printf("What city do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.city);
                break;
            case PRICE:
                cmp = compare_price;
                printf("What price do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.price);
                break;
            case ROOM:
                cmp = compare_room;
                printf("How many rooms do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.room);
                break;
            case BATHROOM:
                cmp = compare_bathroom;
                printf("How many bathrooms price do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.bathroom);
                break;
            case CARPARK:
                cmp = compare_carpark;
                printf("How many carparks do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%d", &target.carpark);
                break;
            case TYPE:
                cmp = compare_type;
                printf("What location do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.type);
                break;
            case FURNISH:
                cmp = compare_furnish;
                printf("What value of furnish do you want to find? ");
                res = scanf("%99s", target.furnish);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            if (!cmp)
                break;

            input_flush();
            if (res != 1) {
                printf("input error\n");
                break;
            }
            data_sort(house, n, cmp);

            int end;
            int idx = data_search(house, n, cmp, &target, &end);
            if (idx >= 0) {
                printf("Data Found. Detail of data:\n");
                data_print(house, idx, end, 1);
                printf("\n");
            } else {
                printf("Data Not Found!\n");
            }
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            int (*cmp)(const void *aa, const void *bb) = NULL;
            switch (+get_data_field()) {
            case LOCATION:
                cmp = compare_location;
                break;
            case CITY:
                cmp = compare_city;
                break;
            case PRICE:
                cmp = compare_price;
                break;
            case ROOM:
                cmp = compare_room;
                break;
            case BATHROOM:
                cmp = compare_bathroom;
                break;
            case CARPARK:
                cmp = compare_carpark;
                break;
            case TYPE:
                cmp = compare_type;
                break;
            case FURNISH:
                cmp = compare_furnish;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            if (!cmp)
                break;

            data_sort(house, n, cmp);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            char fname[100];
            printf("Name of output file: ");
            res = scanf("%99[^\n]", fname);
            input_flush();
            if (res != 1)
                break;
            printf("Number of rows (0 for all): ");
            int rows;
            res = scanf("%d", &rows);
            input_flush();
            if (res != 1)
                break;
            if (rows == 0 || rows > n)
                rows = n;
            int nwritten = data_write(house, fname, 0, rows);
            if (nwritten >= 0) {
                printf("%d records written to %s\n", nwritten, fname);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        default:
            done = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I will try it. For the qsort function. My Lecturer does not allow me to use the built-in qsort function. We have to build the sorting function by ourselves.

Comment: @ZainFirdaus: I modified your quick sort implementation to use a comparison function, similar to that of `qsort` but with typed arguments.

Comment: please don't delete the code which use `qsort` i think i need it for my study purpose.

Comment: @ZainFirdaus: I never posted the code using `qsort`...  I shall modify the answer ti use compatible comparison functions and show you how to use `qsort` as an alternative.

Comment: ok thank you. anyway i still don't understand the logic on the modified searchL. why `else
            high = middle; `

and ` if (low < array_length && !strcmp(array[low].location, target))
        return low; `

Comment: @ZainFirdaus: `high` is the upper (excluded) boundary of the slice. If the entry at `middle` is strictly below the target, then the first position where the target could be is `>= middle + 1` and otherwise it is `<= middle`, so `high = middle` excluded all entries from `middle` up.  This ensures that the slice is always reduced in the loop, so the loop always terminates...

Comment: ...  At the end of the loop, `low == high` and if `low < array_length`, the entry at `low` we can test this entry to see if it is the target or an element greater than the target.  if `!strcmp(array[low].location, target)` then the **first** matching entry is at index `low`, otherwise there is no matching entry.  If `low >= array_length`, there is no matching entry and the target is greater than all entries in the array, hence return `-1`.

Comment: ooh, is that something that called lower bound? i just searching about that and learn that from youtube. i think it's kinda similar. But my brain need time to understand it

Comment: @ZainFirdaus: This implementation of binary search will locate the lowest position in the sorted array where an entry with the target value is located if present or the position where it should be inserted if none is present.  It is usually faster too as there is only a single comparison per iteration.  Also note that neither your quick sort nor `qsort` perform stable sorting, so the entries in the sorted database with identical keys may be in a different relative order from the original data set.  Using merge sort or a hybrid implementation such as Timsort does not have this shortcoming.